# jquery increment var name (think vars are getting overwritten)

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, variables

I think i know why I'm getting my problem but i don't know enough about jquery to fix it.

I'm connecting to database for a list of products and if there's more than one with the same itemid, i call a javascript function.  It is the same function but i added some bits to make it unique so i can get the right prices etc, but this one javascript variable/array is always the same and i think it's overwriting the previously declared var.

The link to my page is http://www.operationbraveheart.org.uk/jcart/testshop.php

I think it's to do with this line or could it be to do with a lot of the vars getting overwitten?

```
var price = item_prices_by_size[size].Price,
```

I had a theory that if i increment the varname so instead of **var form**, i get **var form1**

Here is my jquery function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var item_prices_by_size = <?php
    $blah=1;
    echo '{ ';
    foreach($subitem AS $subsubitem) {
        if($subsubitem['size'] != 'X-Large') {
            echo '"'.$subsubitem['size'].'": { "Price": "'.$subsubitem['price'].'", "ItemId": "'.$subsubitem['itemid'].'-'.$blah.'" },';
        }
        else {
            echo '"'.$subsubitem['size'].'": { "Price": "'.$subsubitem['price'].'", "ItemId": "'.$subsubitem['itemid'].'-'.$blah.'" }';
        }
        $blah++;
    }
    echo'};';
    ?>

    $(function() {

        $('#foo<?php echo $subitem[0]["prodid"] ?>').change(function() {

        var form = $(this).parents('form');

        // Size is whatever the value the user has selected
        var size = $(this).val();

        // Determine the correct price and item ID based on the selected size
        var price = item_prices_by_size[size].Price,
        itemId = item_prices_by_size[size].ItemId;

        form.find('#price<?php echo $subitem[0]['prodid'] ?>').text(price);

        form.find('[name=my-item-price]').val(price);

        // Update the item ID
        form.find('[name=my-item-id]').val(itemId);


        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to output this JS from the server after you make your connection or do you expect to be able to use PHP variables on the client side? If you think you can use server side variables without a middle man (ajax) that is probably a starting point for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to change some of the var names using php as expected the var values were getting replaced by the next form being displayed.

There was no way of finding which var belonged to which form.

Working code now.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    var item_prices_by_size<?php echo $subitem[0]["prodid"] ?> = <?php
                        $blah=1;
                        echo '{ ';
                        foreach($subitem AS $subsubitem) {
                            if($subsubitem['size'] != 'X-Large') {
                                echo '"'.$subsubitem['size'].'": { "Price": "'.$subsubitem['price'].'", "ItemId": "'.$subsubitem['itemid'].'-'.$blah.'" },';
                            }
                            else {
                                echo '"'.$subsubitem['size'].'": { "Price": "'.$subsubitem['price'].'", "ItemId": "'.$subsubitem['itemid'].'-'.$blah.'" }';
                            }
                            $blah++;
                        }
                        echo'};';
                        ?>

        $(function() {


            $('#foo<?php echo $subitem[0]["prodid"] ?>').change(function() {

              var form = $(this).parents('form');

                // Size is whatever the value the user has selected
                var size = $(this).val();

                // Determine the correct price and item ID based on the selected size
                var price<?php echo $subitem[0]["prodid"] ?>  = item_prices_by_size<?php echo $subitem[0]["prodid"] ?>[size].Price,
                    itemId = item_prices_by_size<?php echo $subitem[0]["prodid"] ?>[size].ItemId;

                form.find('#price<?php echo $subitem[0]['prodid'] ?>').text(price<?php echo $subitem[0]["prodid"] ?>);

                form.find('[name=my-item-price]').val(price<?php echo $subitem[0]["prodid"] ?>);

              // Update the item ID
              form.find('[name=my-item-id]').val(itemId);


            });
        });
            </script>
```